# Create a node value with other node information

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm converting an XML using XSLT and I have an xml with one webdocuments node with nodes of type webdocument

```
<webDocuments>
  <WebDocument>
    <id>808924</id>
    <fileName><![CDATA[file name]]></fileName>
    <filePath><![CDATA[.../201504/808924/filename.pdf]]></filePath>
    <hash><![CDATA[1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1]]></hash>
    <title><![CDATA[Primer document]]></title>
    <creationDate class="sql-timestamp">30/05/2012 15:49:57</creationDate>
  </WebDocument>
</webDocuments>
```

And I'm trying to convert filepath node value (filesystem) to an URL. Above, there's an example converted, where param1 should be $hash, the hash node value (in that case 1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1) and param2 should be $id the id node value in that case 808924

```
<webDocuments>
  <WebDocument>
    <id>808924</id>
    <fileName><![CDATA[file name]]></fileName>
    <filePath>http://url.com/param1=$hash&param2=$id</filePath>
    <hash><![CDATA[1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1]]></hash>
    <title><![CDATA[Primer document]]></title>
    <creationDate class="sql-timestamp">30/05/2012 15:49:57</creationDate>
  </WebDocument>
</webDocuments>
```

In summary

```
<filePath>http://url.com/param1=1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1&param2=808924
```

I tried a lot things but I'm not getting my expected result:

```
<xsl:template match="/webDocuments">
    <xsl:for-each select="/WebDocument">
    <xsl:value-of select="$hash"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($baseUrl,$baseCAPUrl,$hash,'&amp;fileId&#61;')"/>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In summary my result is take a node value and use to generate another one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide full code. WHat is `$baseUrl,$baseCAPUrl,$hash`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you need. Theres no real need to use `concat()`, you can just have consecutive `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:text` nodes to achieve what you need here. Also, try and [design "push" templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xdpshpul.html) with `xsl:apply-templates` rather than "pull" templates that use `xsl:for-each`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="WebDocument">
    <WebDocument>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </WebDocument>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="filePath">
    <filePath>
         <!-- change below to the right value -->
      <xsl:variable name="baseUrl">http://url.com</xsl:variable>
         <!-- change below too, but I can't see where you use this in the URL -->
      <xsl:variable name="baseCAPUrl">/CAP/</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$baseUrl"/>
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$baseCAPUrl"/>
      <xsl:text>?param1=</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../hash"/>
      <xsl:text>param2=</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../id"/>
    </filePath>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- XSL identity -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webDocuments>
  <WebDocument>
    <id>808924</id>
    <fileName>file name</fileName>
    <filePath>http://url.com//CAP/?param1=1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1param2=808924</filePath>
    <hash>1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1</hash>
    <title>Primer document</title>
    <creationDate class="sql-timestamp">30/05/2012 15:49:57</creationDate>
  </WebDocument>
</webDocuments>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is your XML is not well-formed, because of this line

```
<filePath>http://url.com/param1=$hash&param2=$id</filePath>
```

The `&` needs to be escaped here. It should really look like this

```
<filePath>http://url.com/param1=$hash&amp;param2=$id</filePath>
```

Anyway, in answer to your problem, it looks like you wish to replace the "variables" in the filePath, with actual values from the XML using the elements with the same name.

You've marked this as XSLT2.0, which is good, because you could use **xsl:analyze-string** here to look for your "variables" such as $hash

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\$\w+">
```

Within this, you can specify what you want to do when you find a "matching-substring". In this case, you want to find the element with the same name as the variable you have just matched (minus the $prefix).

```
<xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="$WebDocument/*[local-name() = substring(current(), 2)]"/>
</xsl:matching-substring>
```

(Where **$WebDocument** is a variable that points to the current **WebDocument** element in this case)

For the 'non-matching' string, you just output them as is

```
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="filePath">
      <xsl:variable name="WebDocument" select=".."/>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\$\w+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
               <xsl:value-of select="$WebDocument/*[local-name() = substring(current(), 2)]"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
               <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
         </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
<webDocuments>
    <WebDocument>
      <id>808924</id>
      <fileName>file name</fileName>
      <filePath>http://url.com/param1=1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1&amp;param2=808924</filePath>
      <hash>1c1bc9f96349fc954cba2dfb58f214b1</hash>
      <title>Primer document</title>
      <creationDate class="sql-timestamp">30/05/2012 15:49:57</creationDate>
  </WebDocument>
</webDocuments>
```

Do note the use of the [XSLT identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) here, to output all the other nodes as-is.